# How to implement dynamic html form in order to add input elements horizontally and vertically with connected lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create a form in which I can add html elements in vertical and horizontal position, and those elements should be connected by lines. Fo example [image]
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the lines:
under what I wrote before add a div

```
<div style="width:1000px;border-top:solid 1px gray;position:absoulte;top:-40px;"></div>
```

add lines as needed. top:40px is only an example, fit the right px you need.
If it does not work get back to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex.
for examle if you want to have 4 inputs in a row:

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-around">
<input style="flex-basis:22%"/>
<input style="flex-basis:22%"/>
<input style="flex-basis:22%"/>
<input style="flex-basis:22%"/></div>
```